# Recover deleted branches after 'git push --mirror'

Tags: git, github

My organization has a remote repository on GitHub that's a fork off of another. I've made a clone on my local machine as well as created a local branch, 'test'. The following is a list of commands that followed:

```
git fetch origin '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
git push --mirror
git push --all
```

What followed next was nothing short of a nightmare. Any branch on the remote that wasn't checked out on my local machine was deleted on the repository. I've done `git branch -a` but that only shows, for the remote, branches that had existed on my local copy. I've done `git reflog show` but that only shows logs on the current branch `HEAD`. Doing `git fsck` shows 6 'dangling commits' and 2 'dangling blobs'. Prior to doing `git push --mirror` the branch had 16 branches, 5 of which were created by our organization and the rest were from the original fork. I understand that similar, if not the same, questions have been asked before but at this point none of them are making sense. My utmost respect and highest gratitude to anyone who can prevent me from getting fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things to try. These first two approaches will help you recover the SHA1s of things that used to be branch tips. But one thing that will be hard to recover is the *names* of the missing branches, unless that was previously known.

1. If some of the branches were recently visited by you, your reflog will have their tips:

   ```
   git reflog
   ```
2. You can create a list of all the dangling and lost-and-found commits with:

   ```
   git fsck --full --no-reflogs --unreachable --lost-found | \
     grep commit | \
     cut -d" " -f3 | \ 
     xargs -n 1 git log -n 1 --pretty=oneline > .git/lost-found.txt
   ```

   and then see if the commits match the missing branches.

If you know the name of a branch you want to recover, then you can also try:

3. You can use [**`git-resurrect.sh`**](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/git-resurrect.sh) in the contrib directory to attempt to "resurrect" past branches by scanning your reflog and other sources. This is extremely slow and can take a long time for large repositories.

Comment: Recovering the names aren't as difficult because most of them are on the original repository that we've forked from. Pardon me if this question is somewhat trivial but some of the branches were later merged into the main branch, so would the created list have the entire history? Or just from the point of merging?

Comment: If the branches still exist, it's their current state that will be recovered. But if they were merged and that's not what you want, don't worry -- it will be obvious where the merge occurred. The commit just before the merge commit that will be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you have filesystem access to the remote that you pushed to, you can recover the deleted branches from `MYREPO.git/info/refs`.

The contents looks something like this.

```
2ef208a632946dd4b5fd6f124a7fd6fc1c2ab87e        refs/heads/foo-feature
7325d39f52d6663e33f360b3bd666300ce2c52b0        refs/heads/bar-feature
```

For each branch you want to recover, create a file in your *local* repo.

```
$ echo 2ef208a632946dd4b5fd6f124a7fd6fc1c2ab87e > .git/refs/heads/foo-feature
```

Then, push your newly-recovered branches back to the server.

```
$ git push --all
```

Comment: what is the difference between 'echo 2ef208a632946dd4b5fd6f124a7fd6fc1c2ab87e > .git/refs/heads/foo-feature' and 'git branch foo-feature 2ef208a632946dd4b5fd6f124a7fd6fc1c2ab87e'? When there is a git command, I would avoid to edit the git datastructures manually.

Answer (score 0):

Below steps worked for me

1. Find the short commit hash of the branch from the cached local repo.

   git reflog show
2. Browse to the GitHub to get the complete commit hash, navigate to below URL and click on the short commit hash to get the complete hash

   https://github.com/ORGANIZATION/REPONAME/tree/SHORTCOMMITHASH
3. type the below command to fetch the commit

   git fetch origin COMPLETECOMMITHASH
4. Create a new branch from the fetched commit

   git checkout -b  FETCH_HEAD
5. Push the created branch to remote

   git push origin